# multi-day vs single day event rendering question in daygridmonth view in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to have my events in 'DayGridMonth' view to render horizontally approximately when the event is supposed to start and end.  I know this is not a feature and not supposed to work, but I have a fixed size calendar, my code below does what I want, except for events that only are rendered in a single day

I cannot get the style to change on request.  None of the events are allDay.  Here is a simplified version of code. The rest of my code accounts for multi-week rendering, but not necessary to help with this question.

I would like the events that do not span multiple days to render like multiple day events and comply with the style changes in the event render hook.

Code:

```
   eventDidMount: function(arg) {
      const event = arg.event;
      const eventElement = arg.el;
      const startDate = event.start;
      const endDate = event.end || event.start;

      const dayCell = eventElement.closest('.fc-daygrid-day');
      const dayCellWidth = dayCell.offsetWidth || 1;
      const eventBlockCell = eventElement.closest('.fc-daygrid-event-harness');
      
      
      var rightValue = parseInt(eventBlockCell.style.right, 10);
      // this is how I delineate between 1 day events because 1 day events do not have a right style. and I am unable to change it
      if (rightValue === 0) {
        rightValue = 0 - dayCellWidth;
      };

        const eventStartMoment = moment(event.start);
        const durationFromStart = eventStartMoment.diff(moment(event.start).startOf('day'), 'minutes');
        const leftPxAmount = durationFromStart / (24 * 60) * dayCellWidth;
        eventBlockCell.style.left = leftPxAmount + 'px';

        const eventEndMoment = moment(event.end);
        const durationFromEnd = eventEndMoment.diff(moment(event.end).endOf('day'), 'minutes');
        const rightPxAmount = Math.abs(durationFromEnd / (24 * 60) * dayCellWidth) + rightValue;
         // one day events seem to not let their style get changed, or at least their right and left       
        eventBlockCell.style.right = rightPxAmount + 'px';
      }
    },
```

Comment: The solution I came up with was to
1) instead of changing the rendering within the eventDidMount, I just used it to create a dictionary with the event title, date, and left/right px amount
2) used a wrapper for the calendar.render()
3) created an exterior function for the style additions
4) used throttled the function to occur after the render is complete
5) put it all in the wrapper for the render function
6) this allowed me to use windowResize with little effort and apply styling to single day events that start/stop at a specific point in the day

Comment: It's great that you solved this, but you need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer is not a passing comment! Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, and to a search engine the question appears un-answered. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) article and [answer] from the help centre is also relevant. Thanks.